# Calculating power requirements of components

Tags: arduino, mosfet

I'm just starting out learning electronics, so please forgive my ignorance. I want to control a bunch of small 10W CLR light bulbs using Arduino. I have this MOSFET module:
http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/34/TinkerKit_MosfetModule-188845.pdf

It says "This module lets you control devices operating at a maximun of 24VDC with an Arduino pin", but nowhere on the data sheet does it tell you the amps. Don't I need to know that in order to calculate how many 10w bulbs I can operate? `W = V * amps` right?

Comment: The Ohm's law notation for power calculation is P = I E (or P = I V)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see how much current you can draw by looking at the [datasheet of the IRF520 device used](http://www.vishay.com/docs/91017/91017.pdf). The IRF520 can have 9.2A @ 25 degrees, but you should never reach this number since its really an absolute max spec as well. 5-6A is likely a more safe bet and it depends on the layout of the device and its power dissipation.

So, with 10W bulbs, each drawing 0.416A, you could have around 14 lamps.

Answer (score 1):

IRF520 is not the best MOSFET for such a device. It has very high on-state resistance - 0.27ohms

On the other hand, in the module discussed, there is no heat sink on the MOSFET. This way, max power of 2-2.5W can be safely dissipated (and the MOSFET will be hot).

It means: \$I_{max} = \sqrt{\dfrac{P_{max}}{R_{on}}} = \sqrt{\dfrac{2.5}{0.27}} ≈ 3A\$

On 24V this gives: \$P_{load} = V_{load}*I_{max} ≈ 24V.3A ≈ 72W\$